# If two separate PATH directories contain a same-named executable, how does Windows choose?

Tags: windows, php, pear

I'm in the process of upgrading PEAR (PHP) on my system. The upgrade script is encouraging me to add "..\PHP\PEAR" to my PATH so that I can use "pear.bat". However, I already am able to use pear.bat.

Looking in my PATH, I see that I don't have any PEAR directories, only my PHP directory. Opening my PHP directory, I see that there's a "pear.bat" in the base. But there's also a pear.bat in the PEAR subfolder of PHP. I'm wondering if I borked a PEAR install.

I digress. So if I leave ..\PHP in my path, but also add ..\PHP\PEAR -- both of which have a "pear.bat" in them -- which one will Windows "choose"? How does Windows decide?

Comment: You could just try it and see. I would expect that since PATH is an ordered list, the first one it found would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First match wins. The `pear.bat` in the directory that comes first in the `%PATH%` is the one that is executed:

- `PATH=..\PHP\PEAR;..\PHP`: `..\PHP\PEAR\pear.bat` is executed
- `PATH=..\PHP;..\PHP\PEAR`: `..\PHP\pear.bat` is executed

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true:

> **Two or more identical file names in the path**
>
> If you have two or more files in the command path that have the same
>   file name and extension, **Windows XP searches for the specified file
>   name first in the current directory, and then it searches the
>   directories in the command path in the order in which they are listed
>   in PATH**.

Agreed, this applies to Windows XP (I can't find any information about other Windows versions), but I don't think this behavior has changed.

EDIT: I could find some information for Windows Server 2008 and Vista here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753427%28v=ws.10%29.aspx (almost same text as above):

> If two or more files in the command path have the same file name and
>   extension, **path first searches for the specified file name in the
>   current directory. Then it searches the directories in the command
>   path in the order that they are listed in the PATH environment
>   variable**.

which seems to confirm the assumption that the behavior hasn't changed across Windows versions.